# Why the ABA on this bank does not correspond to the routing number?

Tags: banking

This is the transfer instruction for anyone that want to send money to choicebank

```
Intermediary Institution: Bank of America, N.A.
NationsBank Tower
100 South East 2nd Street
33131
Miami, Florida
ABA No. 026‐009‐593
Routing 051000017
SWIFT: BOFAUS3M
 
 
Beneficiary Bank: Choice Bank Limited
1 Coney Drive, 3rd Floor
Belize City, Belize
SWIFT: CHOIBZBZ
Account Number: 1901‐1‐06100
```

My understanding is that 1901‐1‐06100 is the bank account number of choice bank in bank of America. So I am basically transfering money to bank of America and then choicebank, recoqnizing it, will credit the money to my account.

Am I correct?

Then there are these 2 numbers that are confusing

```
ABA No. 026‐009‐593
Routing 051000017
```

I understand routing number is. I thought it's number poped by american bank assosiation. Then there is this ABA number again. Also the routing numbers do not match.

This http://www.ehow.com/about_6502241_aba-vs_-bank-routing-number.html shows that it should match.

So, what's wrong?

Comment: https://www.bankofamerica.com/deposits/manage/faq-routing-numbers.go explains that BofA has multiple routing numbers (many banks do) for different regions, and the special one you quote for wire transfers.

Answer (score 1):

Routing number (RTN - Routing Transit Number) you're talking about is the Federal Reserve routing number. It is based on, but not equivalent to ABA numbers. The specific routing number may also be based on ABA numbers of institutions merged into BoA, which are now defunct.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number):

> The RTN number is derived from the bank's transit number originated by
>   the American Bankers Association, which designed it in 1910.